# Can telnet port and url but not not invoke service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, networking

I got an application that invokes a third party, this was working just fine but suddenly I can't invoke the service. I tried with Soap UI, with a web browser and with visual studio; I just can't reach the service. The weird part is that if telnet the service's url and port it will work. Something is listening there. I also thought about something other than a webservice listening there but the service creator provided proof that he's able to invoke the service in the very same URL that's giving me trouble. What am I missing?

Comment: is the remote server external or internal to your network

Comment: Just because you're both using the same URL, that doesn't mean that the URL's are resolving to the *same* machine. Compare DNS, hosts files, etc.

Comment: Not quite sure about the actual architecture, since is quite like a blackbox to me. But I do know that are firewalls along the way.

Comment: Just checked, URL points to the same IP in every machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, mistery solved, in case anyone comes across something similar to this I post what I found out.

Soap UI was not working because proxy settings, if I tell it bypass the proxy then everything was fine. Visual Studio gave a different error because third party changed the wsdl without previous notification. So it was two different errors and that's what was giving me hell.